# How to track logged in user status using redis in sails.js

Tags: redis, sails.js

I'm developing admin panel using redis in sails.js with below mentioned points.

1. It will track all logged in user status.
2. It will be able to logged out any user from admin panel
3. It will store history of all users visited to the portal.

I'm am new in redis. please guide me.

Any answer ( GUI/ Diagram ) will be appreciable.